# Micro Controller test if external circuit is powered

Tags: microcontroller, relay, esp8266

I'm new to electrical stuff, so thanks in advance for all help.  I'm trying to control a window air conditioning unit with a micro controller (ESP8266), and I want to know if the AC is powered on.  I can get a switched 5v line and ground on the AC, but I don't know what I need to put between the AC and the MCU.  I'm using signal relays to "push" buttons on the AC and I am *thinking* I can just reverse the relay so the switched line triggers the relay and it closes a digital pin on the MCU - See below.

[image]

If the relay is the right answer, is it safe to simply wire in a relay to 5v power and ground on the AC, or will that short out something? The pins are marked 5v and G on the AC control panel.

Comment: use R = 0 ohms ... enable D8 internal pullup resistor

Comment: Similar to [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9351/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-monitor-a-120v-line-via-software).